# Exported sql dump file from previous phpMyAdmin profile does not apply to the new one

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

I have changed my OS from windows 8.1 to ubuntu 14.04. On windows I had wamp installed and I exported all my db's before reinstall as sql file.
On ubuntu I use xampp but phpmyadmin throws an error while importing it - #1046 - No database selected.

The database must be chosen, but what if want to replace all databases with others that are in sql file? 
What extra steps I should do to make it import?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is, when exporting, to click the "Custom" export radio button and look for the "Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement" checkbox. Selecting that makes phpMyAdmin include the statements in the SQL file which create and select each database before creating the table structure and importing your data.

"Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement" is in the "Object creation options" area of the custom export display.